# Regex everything outside a commented string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm building a syntax highlighting script for css and i've got a problem with the comments.

Here's a sample of the problem i have. I'm trying to make a regex that selects everything outside the comments, but after hours of failing im posting here.

Here's my input

```
/* Syntax highlighting under construction! */

.content, .styling, #navbar {
   font-family: "SourceCodePro";
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 18px;
}

/* Another comment */

.styling {
   background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
   border: 1px solid rgb(20, 20, 20);
   padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}
```

I wan this output from the regex:

```
.content, .styling, #navbar {
   font-family: "SourceCodePro";
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 18px;
}
.styling {
   background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
   border: 1px solid rgb(20, 20, 20);
   padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}
```

Comment: Show us your current code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourString.replace(/\/\*(.*)\*\//g,'');
```

This will strip the comment blocks (starting with `"/*"` and ending in `"*/"` from your string, which is what you appear to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on your way:

`^(?!/\*).*$`